# How to add react routing to AntD horizontal Menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, antd

I have the below component as the main layout. When I click on the menu item, I want them to navigate to the home, holiday calendar, and event pages. What can I do with this horizontal menu? The below code shows the main layout wrapped around the above pages. I am using AntD and react-router. this main layout is wrapped around all other routers.

```
import { Layout, Menu, Button, Avatar, Row, Col, Space, Dropdown } from "antd";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const navigation = [
  { label: "Home", key: 1 },
  { label: "Holiday Calendar", key: 2 },
  { label: "Event", key: 3 },
];

const MainLayout = () => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const showDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("loadHolidayCalander"));
  };

  const handleLogOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("access-token");

  };
  const menu = (
    <Menu
      items={[
        {
          key: "1",
          label: <Button onClick={handleLogOut}>Log out</Button>,
        },
      ]}
    ></Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Layout style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>      
        <Row style={{ backgroundColor:"#404140"}}>
          <Col
          style={{padding:5, margin:0, height:48}}
            flex="300px"
           >
            <a href="/holiday-calander">
              <img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" style={{ height: 38 }} />
            </a>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Menu              
              theme="dark"
              mode="horizontal"
              defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]}
              items={navigation}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col
            flex="auto"
            style={{

              padding:5

            }}
          >
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", right: "5px" }}>
              <Space size={20}>
                <Dropdown overlay={menu} placement="topRight" arrow>
                  <Avatar  style={{ width: 38, height:38 }} />
                </Dropdown>
              </Space>
            </div>
          </Col>

        </Row>
        
    
      <Layout
        style={{
          padding: 0,
          backgroundColor: "white",
          marginLeft:28,
          marginRight:28,
        }}
      >

        <Outlet />

      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `onClick` handler to the `Menu` component, which will be passed an object with the `key` property you can search the `navigation` array for the matching element.

Add a link target to the `navigation` array elements.

```
import { ..., useNavigate, ... } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigation = [
  { label: "Home", key: 1, target: "/" },
  { label: "Holiday Calendar", key: 2, "/holidaycalendar" },
  { label: "Event", key: 3, "/event" },
];

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleMenuClick = ({ key }) => {
  const { target } = navigation.find(item => item.key === key) || {};
  if (target) {
    navigate(target);
  }
};

...

<Menu              
  theme="dark"
  mode="horizontal"
  defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]}
  items={navigation}
  onClick={handleMenuClick}
/>
```

An improvement could be to make the `key` property the link target.

```
import { ..., useNavigate, ... } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigation = [
  { label: "Home", key: "/" },
  { label: "Holiday Calendar", key: "/holidaycalendar" },
  { label: "Event", key: "/event" },
];

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleMenuClick = ({ key }) => {
  if (key) {
    navigate(key);
  }
};

...

<Menu              
  theme="dark"
  mode="horizontal"
  defaultSelectedKeys={["/holidaycalendar"]}
  items={navigation}
  onClick={handleMenuClick}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can pass `Link` component from rrd to `label` property in `Menu.item` as state in [this link](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/35246#issuecomment-1109782850).

Example :

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
...

items = [
    {
        key: '/home',
        label: <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>,
        icon: <SomeIcon />,
    },
    {
        key: '/menu',
        label: 'This is parent menu',
        icon: <SomeIcon />,
        children: [
            {
                key: '/menu-1',
                label: '<Link to='/menu-1'>Sub Menu 1</Link>,
                icon: <MenuIcon1 />,
            },
            {
                key: '/menu-2',
                label: '<Link to='/menu-2'>Sub Menu 2</Link>,
                icon: <MenuIcon2 />,
            },
    },
]
```

Comment: This should be the correct solution, as this is also working with browser native features like middle mouse or control + click